# how to overrule prior css

Tags: css

why can't I control the < p > tag below with the div class "title left"

```
<td align="left" >
                    <div class="pop-posts-image-left">
                            <a href="http://www.livecrafteat.com/live/meal-planning-template/"> 
                                <img src="http://www.livecrafteat.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/menu-plan-sidebar-thumbnail-2.jpg" alt="" />  
                            </a>
                           <div class="title left">
                                <p text-align="center">  
                                     This Is An Example Post Title 
                                </p> 
                           </div>  
                     </div>
</td>
```

Instead it is being controlled by:

```
body, h1, h2, h2 a, h2 a:visited, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, select, textarea {
color: #70635A;
font-family: "Century Gothic",AppleGothic,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 10px;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 22px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: This SO question might be of some help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850665/how-to-break-css-inheritance/11850747

Comment: You'll want to look into CSS selector specificity. This is how the browser decides which CSS rule to apply. [This](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) is a good write up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it's not applying it now is because CSS styles by tag name take precedence over styles defined with a class.

Using the style you defined you can specify that you want it applied to the `<p>`:

```
.title-left, .title-left p {
    color: #000;    
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

And in the HTML:

```
<div class="title-left"> 
  <p> This Is An Example Post Title </p>
</div>
```

Or alternatively if you only want the style applied to the `<p>` and not the `<div>`:

```
.title-left {
    color: #000;    
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

And in the HTML:

```
<div> 
  <p class="title-left"> This Is An Example Post Title </p>
</div>
```

You can test the modification [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ha4fQ/7/).

Comment: yes tried various variations of that: i.e.  </a><div class="title left"> <p> This Is An Example Post Title </p> </div>    .title left { font-size: 14px; } nothing changes. Also tried .title left p; .pop-post-images-left title left p { ....

Comment: @Dustin: `title` and `left` are two separate classes, so you should override them separately. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: So can I simply change my class to "title-left". Because I tried that as well. i.e. .title-left p { font-size: 14px etc } nothing changes.

Comment: Yes you can but you have to either apply the class directly to the `<p>` tag or do as shown in the code above.

Comment: Thanks all. This actually worked:  .pop-posts-right .title-right p {  I could have swore I tried exactly that to override but I guess not.  One last question -  in this case I use .pop-posts-right .title-right p but not .pop-posts-right .pop-posts-image-right .title right p instead? I.e. I don't need to specify each div but rather the parent div and then the actual div and element I want to control?

Comment: It all depends on how specific you want to be. For example if you are setting the font as `bold` for a `<div>` with class `title` and you want all your `<p>` tags inside the titles to be `bold`, you would only specify `.title p` so that all your `title` `<div>`s look the same.

Comment: To answer your question :P, you don't even need to specify more than `.title-right p` actually.

Answer (score 2):

`title left` is not a class. It's two classes: `title` and `left`

You can apply styles to the P tag using one of them:

```
.title p {your styles}
```

or both, if you want

```
.title.left p {your styles}
```